# How do I fix a React Websocket error from WebSocketClient.js:16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm receiving this error

```
WebSocketClient.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://12.345.678.90:5000/ws' failed: 
WebSocketClient @   WebSocketClient.js:16
initSocket  @   socket.js:24
(anonymous) @   socket.js:48
```

Is this an nginx error? Is this a javascript error? I've found a couple posts addressing this but it doesn't seem like it's a true fix.

Server running Ubuntu in a lightsail box, Python backend/React(js/tsx) frontend.

Here is my nginx.conf file, I'm not sure what else I would need. I tried to build in a handler, as you see, but it doesn't seem to be fixing it.

```
  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      auth_basic "Restricted Content";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      auth_basic "Restricted Content";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
  location /dashboard/ {
    rewrite  ^/dashboard/(.*)  /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://grafana;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
  # Proxy Grafana Live WebSocket connections.
  location /dashboard/api/live/ {
    rewrite  ^/dashboard/(.*)  /$1 break;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://grafana;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
  # Proxy for websocket server test
  location /ws {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
}
}
```

Is this an error with my .tsx?